# Difference between classification and characterization

Tags: terminology

What is the difference between classification and characterization in reference to mathematical objects ?
Some examples will be appreciated.

Comment: These notions are not comparable at all. A classification applies to a whole class of objects (finite simple groups, for instance) while a characterisation applies to a single object, value, or property (the determinant of a matrix for instance, or the invertibility of that matrix).

Comment: You would probably get a more helpful answer if **you** gave some examples: provide some quotes to show where you have seen these terms and why they confuse you.

Comment: I do not understand the close votes here - although I do agree with David's comment, I think this question is fine as it stands. As really Marc van Leeuwen's comment is an answer. So where is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

A type of mathematical object can be classified into different categories or types; each example of the object lies in exactly one category (or is of exactly one type). This is what we call a **classification**. Given a type of mathematical object, it can also be classified in different ways. Here are some examples:

- Classification of [finite simple groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_finite_simple_groups).
- Classification of [semisimple Lie algebras over an algebraically closed field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra#Classification).
- Classification of [one-dimensional manifolds](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/1-manifolds).
- Classification of [closed surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface#Classification_of_closed_surfaces) (connected, compact, two-dimensional manifolds without boundary).
- Classification of [simply connected Riemann surfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformization_theorem).

A mathematical object (or collection of mathematical objects) can be characterised by a collection of properties; that is, it is determined by those properties alone. This is what we call a **characterisation**. In particular, a type of mathematical object is characterised by its definition, but we are often interested in other characterisations. Here are some examples:

- The prime numbers are characterised by their definition: numbers greater than one which have only two factors. However, they are also characterised by the following property: numbers $p$ greater than one such that if $p \mid ab$, then $p \mid a$ or $p \mid b$.
- The invertible matrices are characterised by the properties of being square and having non-zero determinant.
- Infinite sets are characterised by the property of having a proper subset with which it is equinumerous (i.e. there is a bijection between the subset and the set itself).
- Harmonic functions are characterised by the [mean value property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function#The_mean_value_property) (assuming local integrability).

There are many more examples for both lists. If I think of any more instructive ones I'll add them.

**Added Later:** You might find the Wikipedia pages on [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_theorem) and [characterisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterization_%28mathematics%29) useful as well.